# Error while changing a field from CharField to ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

[image]

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator

# Create your models here.
class student(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    semester = models.IntegerField(default=1, validators=[MaxValueValidator(8), MinValueValidator(1)])
    stream = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    roll_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

This is the model I have also registered the model in `admin.py` and in `settings.py`.

[image]

When I am trying to see the student table it hits me with this error, after changing the username column from `CharField` to `ForeignKey`.

When I change back to `Charfield`, the problem is fixed. I cleared all the data using `python manage.py flush`. Then used `makemigration` and `migrate`. But the problem exists still.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: also share your views and the url of the view

Comment: There is no issue with the views this is when i am trying to access the student table in  django admin page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run migrations for your models:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I had already run those commands but it didnot worked now I run those and logedout (which I did not do it early) and log in again Now it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: np, thought it should work :)